# Creating map in R with tmap, but error with crop and mask

Tags: r, tmap

I would like to create a map of China, showing the population density of China with a geotiff file and a shapefile.

I took the population density from this website
https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev11/data-download as a geotiff file. I choose the year 2020.

And the shapefile of China, I took from this website
https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

Now I would like to create a map in tmap but I got always an error messages.

This is my code

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(sf) 
library(tmap)


p_20 <- raster("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_2pt5_min.tif")
CHN <- read_sf("gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1.shp")
CHN <- st_transform(CHN$geometry, 4480)
p_20_crop <- crop(p_20, CHN)
p_20_mask <- mask(p_20_crop, CHN)

tm_shape(p_20_mask) + tm_raster() + tm_layout(legend.position = c("right", "bottom"))
```

I used crop and mask to only have China in the map. But in the line of p_20_crop i got the error message

```
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You don't need all those packages to show your problem. Starting a Q with a big list of packages that someone might not have installed is going to put people off answering. You only need `raster` and `sf` to show your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
CHN <- st_transform(CHN$geometry, 4480)
```

You are taking only the geometry column from `CHN`, and transforming that returns an `sfc` object, not an `sf` data frame.

You then do `crop(p_20, CHN)` and the error message is:

```
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y
```

So argument `y` is your `CHN` and `crop` can't get an extent from it.

The help for `raster::crop` says:

```
   y: Extent object, or any object from which an Extent object can
      be extracted (see Details)
```

and the details says "You can check this with the ‘extent’ function."

and indeed...

```
> extent(CHN)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"sfc_MULTIPOLYGON"’
```

but you *can* get the extent of the original `sf` data frame. Let's read it again and try:

```
> CHN <- st_read("gadm36_CHN_1.shp", quiet=TRUE)
> extent(CHN)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 73.5577 
xmax       : 134.7739 
ymin       : 18.15931 
ymax       : 53.56086
```

If you transform as a data frame, you can get the extent of the transformed data frame:

```
> CHN <- st_transform(CHN, 4480)
> extent(CHN)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 73.5577 
xmax       : 134.7739 
ymin       : 18.15931 
ymax       : 53.56086
```

and then `crop` works.

```
> p_20_crop = crop(p_20, CHN)
> plot(p_20_crop)
> plot(CHN$geometry, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm not sure why you are converting to 4480 when the raster is in 4326. 4480 looks very similar to 4326 so you're not seeing a gross error, but the lack of warning message suprises me.

According to the WKT, the only difference is a tiny factor in the ellipsoid shape:

4480:

```
   DATUM["China 2000",
        ELLIPSOID["CGCS2000",6378137,298.257222101,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
```

4326:

```
   DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
```

(4480 is a 3-d system with a Z coord specified, so it probably does have uses within China, but if you are cropping a 4326 raster then I'd stick with vectors in 4326 and save any conversion to 4480 to a later part of the processing chain).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this might be a namespace issue, since `crop()` is available at least in `{raster}` and `{terra}`. Decide which function you want to call (e.g. `terra::crop()`) and check the input arguments, especially the classes supported, carefully.

Bringing me to the second point: This crazy mix of spatial packages, as @Spacedman has already mentioned in the comment. Please decide consciously which libraries you want to use and only include the ones you actually need. Personally, I'd suggest to go for `{sf}` when dealing with vector data and `{terra}` when dealing with raster data. Hence, you won't really need sp/raster.

Having made some (minor) adjustments, try the following code:

```r
p_20 <- terra::rast("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_2pt5_min.tif")
CHN <- sf::read_sf("gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1.shp")

CHN <- sf::st_transform(CHN, crs = "epsg:4326") |> terra::vect()
p_20_crop <- terra::crop(p_20, CHN)
p_20_mask <- terra::mask(p_20_crop, CHN)
```